# Non-UI BDD for Android

Tags: android, bdd

I need to use a BDD testing framework for Android and most frameworks test on the UI level.
Are there any non-UI frameworks like jBehave running on DVM?

Comment: Have you gotten Robolectric working with jBehave?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far I was able to find one tool called [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org).

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen anyone who has this working yet, but my guess is that you could probably use [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/) to enable it.

Comment: Robotium is a UI testing tool. I need something running on a much lower level.

Comment: Apologies - I typed Robotium, but I meant Robolectric! Which it looks like you've already found :-)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're working on, you could use a framework that allows cross-compiling to the desktop and then still use jBehave. For example, this should be achievable with [libGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/).